# Adding transparent video

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to add a fireworks video on top of my viewcontroller. The background of the video is always black (it is made as transparent) and i am failing to change the background color to clear color. Any suggestions?

```
// In my UIView Subclass

func play(){
    self.layer.opaque = false

    let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("fireworks", withExtension: "mov")!
    let avplayer : AVPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: file)
    let layer = (self.layer as! AVPlayerLayer)
    playerLayer.player = avplayer
    avplayer.play()
}

override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass{
    return AVPlayerLayer.self
}
```

Comment: What is your video format? As far as I know, except for M-JPEG, the iPhone only supports H.264 and that codec doesn't support transparency.

Comment: The video codec is MPEG-4. I also tried H.264 codec. Both of them didn't work.

Comment: There is a non-free library that can be used to render transparent videos: http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/index.html